# Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined,

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a newbie to React.js and I face with a strange error that I can't figure out why that's happening, I searched but and didn't find any solutions.

Here is is my component codes:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const AddMovie = () => {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState({ title: "", director: "" });
  const onChange = (value, filed) => {
    setMovie({
      [filed]: value,
    });
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(movie.title, movie.director);
    setMovie({ title: "", director: "" });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="flex -mx-2" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="ml-2">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="border p-2 rounded-md focus:outline-none"
            placeholder="Movie Title"
            value={movie.title}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value, "title")}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mx-2">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="border p-2 rounded-md focus:outline-none"
            placeholder="director"
            value={movie.director}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value, "director")}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="h-full border rounded-md px-4 text-white bg-gray-900"
          >
            Add Movie
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default AddMovie;
```

and the error that I face with it is this: (i referred to DOC and I read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs) section but it didn't work as well)

`react_devtools_backend.js:3973 Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components`

so what is the problem?
I have done this way of binding (object syntax) in `Vue.js` a lot of times but I haven't been facing this once, so is a bit queer for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to `value={movie.director}` being `undefined` once you change your movie title. That happens because you miss use the setter API,

[With hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) (READ THE NOTE), the state setter does not merge state [as in class component](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged), change it to:

```
// field = 'title'
setMovie(prevState => ({...prevState, [field]: value }))
```

Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does not automatically merge update objects.

> Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does not automatically merge update objects.